# unexpected =>, expecting '}' in rspec expect

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have this code:

```
adapter.send(:conditions_to_fields, :user => user).should == {'owner_id' => user.id}
```

which I updated to use expect with:

```
expect(adapter.send(:conditions_to_fields, :user => user)).to eq {'owner_id' => user.id}
```

but this gives me:

```
syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
... => user)).to eq {'owner_id' => user.id}
```

What did I miss or get wrong with my code that is giving me that error?
Is it a common issue?

Comment: why are you using "expect" when .should matcher looks cleaner and works? :S

Comment: @arieljuod Because `should` is not the preferred syntax, `expect` is. See [RSpec’s New Expectation Syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax) (by one of RSpec’s core contributors).

Answer (score 2):

It thinks you’re passing a block to `eq`, not a hash. You can solve this by using parentheses around the method arguments:

```
expect(adapter.foo).to eq({'owner_id' => user.id})
```

Comment: Well, did this answer your question? Don’t forget to [upvote/accept answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158402) `:)` (Including your own answer if you so choose!)

Answer (score 1):

One way to overcome this is to use `Hash` instead of `{}`

e.g.

```
expect(adapter.send(:conditions_to_fields, :pwner => user)).to eq \
Hash('owner_id' => user.id, 'owner_type' => user.class.name)
```